# Why is this resolution not working?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If i have an equation with two variables, for example:

$x + c = 7$

I want to resolve the equation, so i will do this:

$x = 7 - c $

$7 - c + c = 7$

$0 = 0$

This definitely does not work. I know it does not work, but I do not know how to answer why it does not work?

When we have two variables, we have to have two equations, but why? There we can use the substitution method. But if I only have one equation, I can not use substitution, why?

Comment: What do you mean "resolve the equation"? You're not going to be able to get a single number $x$ and a single number $c$ out of this; you don't have enough information. For example, $x = 7, c = 0$ and $x = 3, c = 4$ are two solutions.

Comment: What's the problem? Lots of algebraic manipulations are true but useless.  $x+c=7\implies x+c+1=8\implies  7+1=8\implies 8=8$.  True but useless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get $x = 7-c$.  If we let $c = 2$ and $x = 9$.... that works.  If we let $c = 3$ and $x = 10$ ... that works.  we can let $c$ be... anything!  And then we will get $x = 7-c$.  We can come up with an infinite number of pairs of solution that work.  But we can't hone it down to exactly one.

If we have more variables than equations we must have one variable *in terms of* the other.  That means the other variable can be anything and the first variable can be multiple values in terms of it.

But if we have the same number of variables as equations we can (usually but not always) isolate each variable by itself so that each variable must have a single value.  We can't *always* do this if we have the same number of variables as equations, but we can *NEVER* do this if we have more variables than (linear) equations.

====

another way to think of this is that if you have

$x + y = 7$ so $y = -x + 7$ that that is the equation of a line.  A line has an infinite number of points.  *Any* point will work.  $x=0, y = 7$ will work.  $x=7; y=0$ will work.  $x = 2; y = 5$ will work, etc.  *every* point on the line will work.

But if you have

$x + y =7$ an $3x - 2y = 6$ then you have:

$y= - x+7$ and $y = \frac 32 x -3$.  Those are *two* equations for *two* lines.  These lines intersect at exactly one point and the point where they intersect is the *only* point they have in common.

$x = 7; y=3$ is the only point that is on both lines.

Comment: I think the last sentence comes off a bit too strongly. The equation $x^2 + y^2 = 0$ *can* be solved explicitly for both $x$ and $y$ over the real numbers.

Comment: Hmm.... dang it.  That is true.

Comment: $y = \pm \sqrt{-x^2}$ so because $x^2 \ge 0$ and we can't have $-x^2 < 0$ we must have $x^2 = 0$.... sigh...That's still getting $y$ in terms of $x$ but using *other* information to limit the choose of $x$ to only one possible value.  The *spirit* of my statment is that if you get $y$ in terms of $x$ then you can have a solution for *every* possible value of $x$.  If we have a situation that there can only be one $x$ that obeys the spirit of my sentence, but not the letter of my sentence.

Comment: Yes, the spirit is absolutely correct. Oh well, (+1) regardless.

Answer (score 1):

If you have one equation but two unknowns, then there are an infinite number of solutions that will work.

Consider your example: x + c = 7
If x is 3 and c is 4, it works
If x is 4 and c is 3, it works
If x is 0 and c is 7, it works

Now let's talk about what you did.
Your manipulations got you to the point where you found 0=0.  This is a true statement.  So it did indeed work, and math always will.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Every solution of $x+c=7$ is also solution of $0=0$.

But, when you substitute something in equation, you may generate new solutions. In this case, not all solutions of $0=0$ is solution of $x+c=7$.

---

Another example:

Let $x=2$.

If we substitute $x$ by $2$, we have $2=2$, which has more solutions than $x=2$.

Comment: I doubt the OP will be able to see your point, clever and subtle (too clever and too subtle) though it is.